# MultiSubnetFailover=true for DBMSes besides SQL Server

Tags: connections, dbms, dns

A connection string for SQL Server can contain MultiSubnetFailover=true, to handle multiple DNS A records, letting the client try to connect to every IP address of a domain (or subdomain) name, to access the current master (of Always On availability groups).

Does this work with other DBMSes, like MySQL?  If not, is there an equivalent?

Comment: In Postgres you can provide multiple IP addresses at connection time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MultiSubnetFailover` can be used only for connecting to SQL Server part of the client connection string.

For MySQL, if you are using .NET, then you can [use multiple hosts in connection string or you can even use single DNS that provide DNS Service (SRV) records to provide failover, load balancing, and replication services](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-string.html).

Comment: Thank you!  Just what I needed.